# Is there a way to un-distribute a union of tuples?

Tags: typescript

I have a union of tuples of varying lengths.

```
type Input =
  | [a, b, c]
  | [d, e]
  | [f, g]
```

I want to "un-distribute" these into a single tuple. Each item in the tuple is an intersection of all of the items in all of the input tuples.

```
Transform<Input> // [a & d & f, b & e & g, c]
```

Some examples

```
// Merge objects
Transform<[ { foo: 1 } ] | [ { bar: 2 } ]> // [ { foo: 1, bar: 2 } ]

// Ignore labels
Transform<[x: { foo: 1 } ] | [ y: { bar: 2 } ]> // [ { foo: 1, bar: 2 } ]

// Items can be `never` when appropriate
Transform<[ number ] | [ string ]> // [ never ]

// Works with arrays
Transform<{ foo: 1 }[] | { bar: 2 }[]> // { foo: 1, bar: 2 }[]

// Works with spreads
Transform<[ { foo: 1 }, ...{ baz: 3 }[] ] | [ { bar: 2 }, ...{ boo: 4 }[] ]>
  // [ { foo: 1, bar: 2 }, ...{ baz: 3, boo: 4 }[] ]

// Works with empty tuple
Transform<[]> // []

// Works with single tuple
Transform<[ 'a' ]> // [ 'a' ]
```

Comment: ① Do you have a typo in your first example? Why would `g` be in the third element of the output? Please [edit] to be sure you have a [mre] here.

Comment: ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAL28N) meet your needs? Please test thoroughly against expected use/edge cases; deeply recursive types tend to have bizarre edge cases that require significant refactoring to change, so I want to be sure it satisfies before proceeding. In particular I expect weird things to happen when mixing fixed-length and open-ended tuples, and tuples with leading/middle rest elements.  If it does meet your needs I could write up an answer explaining. If not, please [edit] to clarify the unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: > Do you have a typo in your first example? Why would g be in the third element of the output? Please edit to be sure you have a minimal reproducible example here

I sure did. Fixed with apologies.

> Does this approach meet your needs?

I do believe it does. I'm going to poke at it for a looong time, but nothing is immediately jumping out at me. What kinds of issues were you seeing?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I haven’t seen any issues because I don’t have use cases… but I expect “interesting” things to happen if you use things like optional tuple members, or non-final rest elements, or if you mix-and-match different types of tuples.  How “looong” do you think you’ll need before knowing if this approach is acceptable or not?  If it’s more than a day or two maybe at some point I should write an answer, and then if you find a problem later you can open a new question for it.

Comment: This works with everything I've tried. I haven't seen anything "interesting". I'm not worried about non-final spread values (these tuples come from function params ultimately). Trailing optional values seem to work. Thanks a ton. This has stumped me for weeks.

Comment: Okay I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance, might not be today ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A caveat to start: this sort of recursive type juggling with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) tends to result in very bizarre edge case behavior.  Anytime you've got a utility type like this you should be sure to test it thoroughly to make sure it behaves as expected with your use cases.

So, we want to write `Transform<T>` where `T` is expected to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of array/tuple types.  It's going to be a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that accumulates a partial result `A`, so it will actually be `Transform<T, A>`.  The general approach is to split `T` into a head element (similar to the union of the head elements of each member of `T`), and a tail array (the union of the tail arrays of each member of `T`).  The head element needs to be [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) together, and we will recurse on the tail array.

There are three cases to detect:

- every member of `T` is the empty tuple `[]`.  That means we've run out of data to process; there is no head element or tail array. We can just return the accumulated result `A`
- every member of `T` is a non-tuple array type. That means we've been asked to process a bunch of arrays without end and whose structure will not change further if we keep iterating.  We can process the head element and then append an array of the resulting type as a [rest element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) to the accumulated result `A`, and return it.
- otherwise, at least one member of `T` is a tuple type with a head element and a tail array.  This is the recursive step; we intersect all the head elements of the members that have them and append it to `A`, and recurse on the tail array.

That looks like

```
type Transform<T extends any[], A extends any[] = []> =
    Tail<T> extends never ? A :
    NonRest<T> extends never ? [...A, ...IntersectHead<T>[]] :
    Transform<Tail<T>, [...A, IntersectHead<T>]>;
```

Note that this is *not* a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  The check for those three cases needs to analyze the whole union input at once, not split it apart and analyze each piece separately.

That definition depends on `Tail<T>`, which evaluates to the tail of the array:

```
type Tail<T extends any[]> =
    T extends [any, ...infer R] ? R : T extends [] ? never : T;
```

So `Tail<[H, ...R]>` should be `R`, and `Tail<X[]>` should be `X[]`, but `Tail<[]>` is `never`.  And since `Tail` *is* a distributive conditional type, the only way `never` comes out is for all the inputs to be empty.

The definition also depends on `NonRest<T>`, which looks for even one tuple-like element, returning `unknown` if it finds one and `never` if it does not:

```
type NonRest<T extends any[]> =
    T extends [any, ...any] ? unknown : T extends [] ? unknown : never;
```

Again, it's a conditional type. So if any element of `T` is a tuple, the output will be `unknown`.  Only if `NonRest<T> extends never` do we know that all elements are non-tuple array types.

And finally it depends on `IntersectHead<T>`, which gives the intersection of the head elements of `T`:

```
type IntersectHead<T extends any[]> = (
    T extends [infer F, ...any] ? (x: F) => void : T extends [] ? never : (x: T[0]) => void
) extends (x: infer I) => void ? I : never
```

This is similar to `UnionToIntersection` from [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218), except that it first pulls the head element off the input instead of just intersecting the input directly.  This allows things like `Transform<[A | B] | [C | D]>` to evaluate to `[(A | B) & (C | D)]` instead of `[A & B & C & D]`.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
type Input = [A, B, C] | [D, E] | [F, G];
type Output = Transform<Input>; // type Output = [A & D & F, B & E & G, C]

type Z = Transform<[{ foo: 1 }] | [{ bar: 2 }]>
// type Z = [{ foo: 1; } & { bar: 2; }]

type Y = Transform<[x: { foo: 1 }] | [y: { bar: 2 }]>
// type Y = [{ foo: 1; } & { bar: 2; }]

type X = Transform<[number] | [string]>
// type X = [never]

type W = Transform<{ foo: 1 }[] | { bar: 2 }[]>
// type W = ({ foo: 1; } & { bar: 2; })[]

type V = Transform<[{ foo: 1 }, ...{ baz: 3 }[]] | [{ bar: 2 }, ...{ boo: 4 }[]]>
// type V = [{ foo: 1; } & { bar: 2; }, ...({ baz: 3;} & { boo: 4; })[]]

type U = Transform<[]>
// type U = []

type T = Transform<['a']>
// type T = ["a"]*/
```

Looks good, these are the types you wanted them to be.

Again, this needs to be tested *thoroughly* against a wide range of real-world use cases before one considers adopting it.  Since none of the examples in the question involved [optional elements in tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) then it might not do "the right thing" in such cases.  I'd also be especially concerned about mixing and matching of different types of inputs.  At this point any tweaking that needs to happen in response to such cases is out of scope for this question as asked, but it's still a good idea to do testing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgSwDYB4ZQgD2BAdgEwGco5cQBtAXQD4oBeAKCmdg2zyKnNJABooAdEIS4AZhABOUAEqUoAfhlQAXKyw4CxKgqi4IAN0krYAbgYNQkKADkA9rmkRCwNGw2ceVWoxZr2mrh5+IQEeOUUAV1wAa1xbAHdcY3R1Di1wqCjYhKTVPUMJMwtwaABJXBwJQggAY2AACQg4fFdUgM8aeigACiYWFP9OchFxKQAxYKEwnW7MVTGASnpafVsEfGS3NK4M-KNVWdUYcgAGSiW6FbX8BiW2zkOoEaNSi6v1nVLjPYlzc0toDAJKRCKJbBIALatQbEDr8ACCW3aZG0dB23j6zHgyDQtHuxB+OkRykxNnsjmcuKRnEJinIIXhkwE5Uq1TqjWauKochJviBILBkLQiFQMGo-HpQkZUBZkjZDSaLTFNCKIkqojgNWgiIA3iRVABGKAAXyeFUkGq1UAAQlA9QAjVQAJhNZvVmugAGE7VAaqoAMyutUWj1QAAiPvwqgALCaGMGJJboABRH0QVQAViD5sTobGPtEqgAbNn3VaAOI+gDmqgA7HGATLcGAIsAuuRpdb+J65AAfLhh-jJvtcCZQcuUMyNgDyrZbbbR-NwoPBUPK8+oJigAHpt1AZ3PW+3EQAycNQM9j21n1Nn8vdyj-EpQABaXSXK6F5D1YNshpNI7flA9pwBIzoAdQDC7vuz5vmiQG-oaW6mmeDqgc6yGPsUVgAJrvsCy6ClC5BzAWth-lARrGoBICqGhYFQC61GQdBjZ4fBP7kUhrqocB6GMZhT5WAAGvhAqrig5C4BEEL2pIgHOBIIhVjQUF7o2onwT8WGNgA6mJhESZxFFUdo-b0eBxpeGpMFWPpaLdMZ3EoT6IEMU6yELFQQnQAAagZn7EU5lEmkyaEAF4Bia3JQP2QFuZZYXAVxUCxlZlCqaxz7+RxUCIZRyEXq5-EeaFghCI5fGRVA-omC5DopdGnncj5UAAKoBURkmZepz4dfBOnPugi4EYFkkAORwONPW2YC7YAERwPNlAAFTbgwQA)